# R transformation of an image to top view

Tags: r, projection-matrix

I have an image that I want to change it's perspective to top view (It was taken from a side of a room and I want to see it from above).
I have managed to calculate transformation matrix but the coordinates were transformed to decimal numbers.
How can I plot the transformed image if I only have the transformed decimal coordinates?
I know it's a weird question but I am having difficulty understanding how to implement the transformation in R.
Below is a data frame containing an example of 10 coordinates before and after transformation .
Thankyou in advance :)

```
     X.before Y.before X.after   Y.after
1         0        0 -141.9455 -40.99561
2         1        0 -141.4526 -40.99561
3         2        0 -140.9597 -40.99561
4         3        0 -140.4668 -40.99561
5         4        0 -139.9738 -40.99561
6         5        0 -139.4809 -40.99561
7         6        0 -138.9880 -40.99561
8         7        0 -138.4951 -40.99561
9         8        0 -138.0021 -40.99561
10        9        0 -137.5092 -40.99561
11       10        0 -137.0163 -40.99561
12       11        0 -136.5234 -40.99561
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example set of the coordinates?

Comment: Yes, thankyou . I added an example to the question